# How to format pence as pounds and pence?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to read out a value from the database in pence.

For example, if I read out 1345 pence, this is £13.45.

What is the best way to ALWAYS put a dot after the first 2 decimal places?

Comment: u can use a number_format or printf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide it by 100?

```
1345 / 100 = 13.45
```

Comment: Just be careful if the number ends in a zero, such as 1340, it will appear in string form as 13.4, not 13.40. You will need to pad it with zero(s) using string formatting.

Comment: @devios You would normally use FORMAT for that (or handle it in presentation code)

Answer (score 7):

You need to watch out for numbers ending in 0. Dividing by 100 will remove them in your final price.

EG: 1290/100 will return 12.9.

---

Try using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
number_format($price/100, 2);

$price = 1345;
//returns 13.45

$price = 1200
//returns 12.00

$price = 1290
//returns 12.90
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The currently 'correct' answer doesn't handle numbers ending in zero which is important.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [MySQL math function reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)

How about

```
Select format(amt/100.0,'#,###,###.##') from mytable
```